# Setting up Microsoft Exchange email on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, ms-exchange

I am a new Ubuntu user and was looking for a way to setup my university email account (Microsoft Exchange) on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. During my preliminary search I found out that Evolution mail client can do the job for free (found a lot of tutorials for setting it up on previous versions of Ubuntu) but unfortunately, couldn't find an article/blog to make it work my system (20.04 LTS). I am facing dependency issues while installing it (refer to the image) and when I try to install the dependency packages, it shows the same error i.e.

```
abhilash@friday:~$ sudo apt install evolution
[sudo] password for abhilash: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 evolution : Depends: libevolution (>= 3.36.1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libevolution (< 3.37) but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: evolution-plugins but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: evolution-plugin-bogofilter but it is not going to be installed or
                         evolution-plugin-spamassassin but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: evolution-plugin-pstimport but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Apologies if this is a trivial question, but I could not find a straightforward solution on the internet hence request the community for suggestions.

Update: As pointed out by @Jos, I am adding the output of `

```
abhilash@friday:`~$ apt policy evolution

evolution:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.36.1-2
  Version table:
     3.36.1-2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: This is a strange error, probably a packaging bug: `libevolution` is to be installed in mutually exclusive versions. Try `sudo apt install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. If there is any interesting output, edit your question and add it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Jos, I tried your suggestion but it is throwing the same error.

Comment: You could try removing `libevolution` first: `sudo apt remove libevolution` in case it was left over from a previous attempt.

Comment: @Jos, it is throwing this error - " Package 'libevolution' is not installed, so not removed "

Comment: Please add the output of `apt policy evolution` to your question.

Comment: Don't screenshot terminal output, copy/paste it into your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Thomas, I updated my question.

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` recently?